# How to remove elements from QStringList by comparing each other members

Tags: c++, qt

I have one QStringList code which are having some file names.

I need to compare each file content and erase the file name if it has having indentical content. I need to delete the file name which are having indentical content and file name is greater in ascending order.

Suppose there are 5 files with name
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test5

first i will compare the file contents of Test 1 and Test 2 and if content matches the delete Test 1 from the list and the compare contenst of Test 2 and Test 3 and if contents not matches than do +1 to the iteration and compare the contents of Test3 and Test4 and if contents matches then remove Test3 and then comapare contents Test2 and Test4..

How can I do with the help of iterators. I am very afraid of invalidating the iterators using erase.

Comment: Try with [QMutableStringListIterator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#QMutableStringListIterator-typedef)

Comment: @Pedro
I tried but code seems not work .
I need to compare each file in list with another and remove the file if file has same contents and doing string comparison the name of the file which is less should be deleted.

Comment: [`QStringList`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#details) is in fact not what the name pretends: _It provides fast index-based access as well as fast insertions and removals._ Instead of fiddling with iterators, you could just use indices (like for an array or `std::vector`). That's not that fancy but easy to read and write (for humans), and will make your erase issue easy to handle.

Answer (score 1):

As ***@Scheff*** mentioned, I think you can use indices directly with `QStringList::operator[]()`, this way you'll not risk iterator invalidation at all.

Then, you can iterate over your list of file names in reverse order (from the last element to the first).
For each element, you iterate again (inner loop) from the beginning to the previous of the current element.
If the current element and the inner current element have the same contents, then you can remove the current element.
As you are iterating in reverse order, you don't disrupt the next iterations (the removed elements are guaranteed to be outside/after of the ranges that will be iterated by the next iterations).

It is hard to explain that kind of algorithm with only words so here is a code sample that illustrates what I mean:

```
void remove_duplicates(QStringList & filenames)
{
    for(int ri = filenames.size()-1; ri >= 0; --ri)
    {
        bool duplicate_found = false;
        for(int i = 0; !duplicate_found && i < ri; ++i)
        {
            if(is_same_contents(filenames[ri], filenames[i]))
            {
                filenames.removeAt(ri);
                duplicate_found = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I assumed here that there is a function that compares two files for contents equality defined as:

```
bool is_same_contents(const QString & filenameA, const QString & filenameB);
```

I have tested it and it works.